# Maintain/Build Debian packages from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packages, build

It looks like it is possible to cross-build Debian packages from Ubuntu, but all the documents I found from the Internet are not very clear.

I'm wondering if someone can give me some clear and simple instructions.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can actually install debian binary packages via (Ubuntu's) apt-get, simply by changing the `sources.list` file to point to debian main.

Comment: Remember, that apt-get is really debian's tool, which Ubuntu borrows... So debian packages are already compatible with Ubuntu's package manager.

Comment: Of course, Debian and Ubuntu have different policies, and differing system configurations. This could bite you at some point, but idk.

Comment: thanks @jpaugh. I think the better approach is to install Debian chroot, and build there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in comment xpt, `chroot` is path to go. I wanted to add `cowbuild` which makes such workflow very easy working with multiple distributions and releases.

Guide: [wiki.debian.org/cowbuilder](https://wiki.debian.org/cowbuilder)

Comment: I'll accept it, because, after nearly 10 years, this is the only answer I got. But honestly, I'm using docker now.